# Is there any way to nest 2 different object in handlebars with node js

Tags: handlebars.js, each

I am trying to use each using handlebars for iterating over 2 objects of type array, when I iterate over them individually that works fine; but when there is a nesting of both inner object each isn't working.

```
a = [{a: "A"}, {a: "B"}, {a: "C"}]
b = [{b: "X"}, {b: "Y"}, {b: "Z"}]
```

Now these both objects can be iterated fine with

```
{{#each a}}
    {{this.a}}
{{/each}}
{{#each b}}
    {{this.b}}
{{/each}}
```

But it wont work for

```
{{#each a}}
    {{this.a}} //this is getting printed

    {{#each b}}
        {{this.b}} //this isn't getting printed
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

(I've not mentioned any HTML syntax to reduce any confusions )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your data context is different when you are within the `#each` block. Within `#each`, your context is the current element in the iteration, `{ a: "A" }`, `{ b: "B" }`, etc. To access an object of the parent context you use [Handlebars Paths](http://handlebarsjs.com/#paths):

```
{{#each a}}
    {{this.a}}
    {{#each ../b}}
        {{this.b}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```